# Installing packages won't work PYTHON 2.7

Tags: python, path, install.packages

I have run setup.py and installed, my script/package it all appears in Python27\Lib\site-packages in a folder with the relevant .egg.info file.

However, after adding site-packages to my PATH I cannot run the relevant scripts.

```
python: cant open file 'mypackage': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What have I missed?

Essentially I would like to install the package, several modules are included in a folder with __init and __main files.  Once installed I would like to just run

```
python mypackage inputfile.txt
```

however mypackage is not found.  I will use optparse for taking in the txt files, but that is irrelevant as I can't get the packages installed.

Comment: You haven't said what you've installed, what "relevant scripts" you're trying to run or how you are running them, or why you think you need to add site-packages to your PATH.

Comment: @DanielRoseman a folder filled with my relevant modules. Also  __main__.py and also __init__.py ...

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, *scripts* do not go in `site-packages`. On the MS-windows platform they generally go in `C:\Python27\Scripts\`.

So on MS-Windows you probably want to add `C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\` to your `$PATH`.

Additionally, you have to [associate](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts) the `.py` filetype with python.

In general, the whole chapter [Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#using-python-on-windows) of the official CPython documentation should be considered required reading for users of Python on Windows.